# Should this question be split into 5 separate questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

I found [What are the steps to deploy OpenStack in a VM using juju?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377353/what-are-the-steps-to-deploy-openstack-in-a-vm-using-juju).

I saw comments on the question earlier that look like the person asking this is really trying to find the answer. It appears he has tried to figure it out himself, but is confused, so I'm inclined to take the time and try to answer it.

He has 5 numbered (and some of them have sub questions) questions.

I only feel qualified to answer 3 or 4 of the questions, and so have been holding off on trying to answer it. I'm considering just answering what I know and people can edit my answer with what I don't know, but the question is long enough that I think I might have to quote it just to keep the answers associated with their question.

Should this be split into multiple questions?

Comment: Either, comment so he separates each of his questions or flag it as unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are are related to the same subject, deploying OpenStack with Juju on "bare metal". With the exception of question two, they can all be answered in one swoop. Just because he offers five points doesn't mean they are five questions.

The user has taken quite a lot of time to outline what they have tried, what their thinking is, and what their goal is. Don't mind the five questions a much as focus on the goal. Deploy OpenStack on two machines with Juju. The rest of the points are simply there to document what the user has tried so far.